# Get-WMIObject results as separate strings

Tags: powershell, printing, wmi

I'm trying to get the results of a powershell command as separate strings.  Here's the command:

```
$PrinterNames = Get-WMIObject win32_printer -computername compname | where {$_.PrinterState -eq "2"} | Select -Object -Name
```

I want to add a line to a log file with a command similar to the following:

```
Add-Content $LogFile -Value "$CurrentDate Printers on this computer have jobs in error.  The printer names are: $PrinterNames."
```

I can't get the $PrinterNames variable to write to the log as text.  When I try the original command above it adds the sentence in quotes but leaves the $PrinterNames part blank.  I tried adding the following to the variable:

```
... | Out-String -stream
```

This did add some text to the log file, but it wasn't formatted how I wanted it.  It looked like this:

### Name

Printer Name A
Printer Name B
etc.

How do I store the printers names in the variable and append them to the log file? I just wanted the names listed out at the end of a sentence.

Comment: Remove the `Select` command on the first line and then replace `$PrinterNames` with `$($PrinterNames.ShareName -join ', ')` in the second line, and you should be fine.

Comment: You can also change `select-object name` to `Select-Object -expandProperty name`, along with `out-string`, but it won't have the comma between the printers.

Comment: And you can both submit as answer so we can close this question. :-)

Comment: I tried the first suggestion, but it doesn't write out the printer names to the log.  The last line of the log reads "The printers are ."  I also tried Xpw's suggestion and it worked, but is there a way to add the comma between the printer names?